# Pairwise Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Given $n$-length bit strings of the form $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$, where $P(b_i=0) = P(b_i=1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and knowledge of all pairwise probabilities $P(b_i=b_j), 1 \leq i \lt j \leq n$, is it possible to calculate the probability, $P_B(B_1=B_2)$, that 2 strings chosen at random are the same?

I can calculate $P_B$ for $n=1,2$, but my intuition is stopping me there, insisting that I need knowledge of *how* $b_1$ and $b_2$ are correlated to decide how much information a 3rd bit adds. I picture this in my head as a Venn diagram, where the non-overlapping area of $b_3$ describes how much information is added; it seems I can’t derive that value without knowing exactly how $b_3$ intersects $b_2$ and $b_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not possible for $n\geq 4$, so you only need to check manually for $n=3$. Here is why. Full distribution of $B$ is determined by $2^n$ probabilities $p_s$ of all possible strings $s$. Marginal distributions of $b_i$ give you $2n$ linear constraints and knowledge of $P(b_i=b_j)$ gives you another $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ linear constraints (some of these constraints might be redundant). You, however, are looking for $$P(B_1=B_2)=\sum_{s\in{\{0,1\}^n}} p_s^2$$
which is a non-linear function of $p_s$'s, so the only way for it to be determined is if the constraints fully determine probabilities $p_s$. It is NOT the case if $2^n>2n+\frac {n(n-1)}2$ which holds $n\geq 4$.

**ETA:** For $n=3$, it can be manually shown that 6 linear conditions imposed by marginal distrubtutions amount only to 4 unique independent ones, which means we can't determine $P_3(B_1=B_2)$.

We also need to deal with degenerate cases $P(b_i=b_j)\in \{0,1\}$ which mean that $b_i$ fully determines $b_j$ (and vice versa). Since this relation is also transitive, the whole set of $n$ bits can be divided up into disjoint classes $C_i$ such that each class behaves as a single bit (if $|C_i|>1$ assign $0,1$ to these 2 equiviprobable states in arbitrary manner) and $P(C_i=C_j)\neq0,1$ for $i\neq j$. Then we can apply reasoning above.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: @DrewCummins I added the answer for $n=3$ (you can't) and pre-processing step to eliminate degenerate $P(b_i=b_j)\in\{0,1\}$ so that dimensionality argument can be correctly applied.